# Converting valid QFile to QString - QString is empty

Tags: c++, string, qt, file, c++11

So I am trying to convert a QFile into a QString by doing the following:

```
void MainWindow::openTemplateFile(QString location)
{
    if (location.isEmpty())
        return;
    else
    {
        QString variable;
        templateFile.setFileName(location);
        if (!templateFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Unable to open template", 
            templateFile.errorString());
            return;
        }

        else    // file opened and ready to read from
        {
            QTextStream in(&templateFile);
            QString fileText = in.readAll();
            qDebug() << templateFile.size() << in.readAll();
        }
    }
}
```

However, in I get the following result in the debug console:

```
48 ""
```

templateFile does exist and is part of the MainWindow class. This is also simplified code - in the actual program I read chars from the file and it works correctly. The location string is a result of the QFileDialog::getOpenFileName function, which I open a txt file with.

Comment: Two comments: (1) the `readAll()` method has no way to report errors, and (2) the method returns a `QByteArray` (not a `QString`), and that `QString` constructor will stop at the first "0" in the array. If there are bytes of "0", the string will be shorter.

Comment: @bnaecker so how would you efficiently read a QFile’s contents to a QString?

Comment: @bnaecker The OP calls `QTextStream::readAll()`, not `QFile::readAll()`. The former does too return a `QString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `readAll()` twice. The second time, the stream is positioned at end-of-file, and so `readAll()` has nothing to read and returns an empty string. Print `fileText` in your debug output instead.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. This was just some messy debugging